# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable in my 2D array game

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, 2d

```
#getting choice of world
"""
  @worldChoice
  @Arguments: 
  @takes in user input for world choice
  @returns the chosen world choice
"""      
    def worldChoice():
        #local variables and constants
        whileLoopWorld = True
        worldChoice = 0
        world = []
        EMPTY = 1
        SINGLE_CRITTER = 2
        SINGLE_BIRTH = 3
        SIMPLE_BIRTH = 4
        EDGEY_TESTING = 5
        COMPLEX_WORLD = 6

    while(whileLoopWorld):
        worldChoice = int(input( """Choices for starting biospheres
  (1) Empty
  (2) Single critter 
  (3) Single birth
  (4) Simple birth
  (5) Edgey testing
  (6) It's a complex world

Selection: """))

        if worldChoice == EMPTY:
            world = oneEmpty()
            whileLoopWorld = False

        if worldChoice == SINGLE_CRITTER:
            world = twoSingleCritter()
            whileLoopWorld = False

        if worldChoice == SINGLE_BIRTH:
            world = threeSingleBirth()
            whileLoopWorld = False

        if worldChoice == SIMPLE_BIRTH:
            world = fourthSimpleBirth()
            whileLoopWorld = False

        if worldChoice == EDGEY_TESTING:
            world = fifthCreateListEdgeCases()
            whileLoopWorld = False

        if worldChoice == COMPLEX_WORLD:
            world = sixthComplexCases()
            whileLoopWorld = False

        else:
            print("\nError: %d is not a valid selection, select one of the following choices\n"%worldChoice)

    return world
```

The function ^ im calling

How I am calling the function:
    oldWorld = worldChoice()

If I were to take the body of the code from my function and put it in my start function it performs normally, but in the situation I am in I am unable to keep it in my start function

Comment: Your function is named `worldChoice()` and you have a variable named `worldChoice`. That seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: oh my I didn't catch that thanks